# Acumatica Filtering PXSelector witth quick search

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom dac and pxselector like this :

[image]
With quick search (red bordered search) I want to filter with every properties. For example with Waybill Type, Transportation Type, Status etc.  But quick search works  only for Reference Nbr.

Of course you can filter from columns but in business requirements I need to filter from quick search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use FastFilterFields property of the GridProperties element to achieve that. You need to add all the fields you need for the search function in FastFilterFields:

```
<px:PXSelector ID="SelectorID" runat="server" DataField="SelectorField">
    <GridProperties FastFilterFields="ReferenceNbr, WaybillType, TransportationType, Status, WaybillNumber, WaybillState" />
</px:PXSelector>
```

If the selector is in a grid instead of a form, use RowTemplate:

```
<px:PXGrid ID="gridID" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds">
    <Levels>
        <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="GridDataView">
            <RowTemplate>
                <px:PXSelector ID="edSelectorID" runat="server" DataField="SelectorField">
                    <GridProperties FastFilterFields="ReferenceNbr, WaybillType, TransportationType, Status, WaybillNumber, WaybillState" />            
                </px:PXSelector>    
            </RowTemplate>
            <Columns>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SelectorField" />
            </Columns>
        </px:PXGridLevel>
    </Levels>
</px:PXGrid>
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that it cannot be done for report parameters and generic inquries due to the fact you need to edit the page for this setting. By default the main field you are selecting and the description field (if you define one) are the only searchable fields unless adding FastFilterFields on a page. If using a selector with a Join you use the double underscore syntax such as "InventoryItem__Descr" when "InventoryItem" is a joined table and the Descr field must be searchable in the FastFilterFields