# Set selector as multifilter posible?

Tags: acumatica

Hello all (Sorry for my english).
I want to filter by some columns when i add a Sales Order Line (Detail) to my Sales Order.
Look the next image.
Red: When i enter text i want to filter by two columns, in this example for Description and Type.
Green: The first line must be the one that the filter return me because is "Case Labor" on Description column and "Labor" on Type column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyRSA.png)

It's an example of how i need to filter mi Inventorys Items on Sales Order Lines.

Comment: @Alan the platform is built on ASP.Net Framework and requires development using C# and ASPX.

Answer (score 0):

You can add filtering to other columns using the `FastFilterFields` property as explained in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47076876/7376238

Besides that most behaviors of the selector dialog is not customizable.

To implement custom filter behavior you would have to implement a smart panel dialog:

[image: the]

Reference: https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=2fe4a5bb-c249-4d30-b117-af8d1671a589

Comment: Yes, i know i can use "Add Stock Item" but the Description and ItemClass is only a reference to what i need.
I need to filter for some fields in the OrderLine selector.
Is it posible?

Comment: Answer is in my answer. With Selector window there is very limited customizability, you can tell the Selector which fields it should filter on using FastFilterFields but that's pretty much all you can do. There's no way to customize these types of dialogs. I'm not saying you need to use 'Add Stock Item', I'm saying you need to create the same type of dialog window which is called a Smart Panel and manually implement the filter like it was done in 'Add Stock Items' if your custom filtering behavior is a hard requirement. Its going to be more difficult than setting a simple selector property.

Comment: You can tell the selector on which field it should filter using 'FastFilterFields' but you can absolutely not control how it filters. The following requirement sounds like you want to modify the filtering behavior which selector doesn't support so smart panel would be the way to go: "The first line must be the one that the filter return me because is "Case Labor" on Description column and "Labor" on Type column."